# Flip characters python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that randomly flips two letters of a word other than the first and last characters. For instance, if the user input "beginner" the output would be "begnnier" where the only two characters flipped were the `i` and `n`. This is what I have so far. The problem is that my function flips all the characters rather than just two .

```
from random import randint

def scramble(word):
    result = word[0]

    if len(word) > 1:
        for i in range(len(word) - 2, 0, -1):
            result += word[i]

        result += word[len(word) - 1]

    return result


def main():
    while True:
      word = input("Please enter a word, type Q to quit the program")
      if word == "Q":
          break
      print(scramble(word))

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use random and either splice the string as in the other answers or convert to a list, swap, and then convert back to a string.

```
import random
def swap_two_chars(s):
    if len(s) <= 3:
        return s
    i,j = random.sample(range(1, len(s)-1), 2)
    sl = list(s)
    sl[i], sl[j] = sl[j], sl[i]
    return ''.join(sl)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    print(swap_two_chars(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Alternatively, `i,j = random.sample(range(1, len(s)-1), 2)`.

Comment: Alternatively alternatively, `i = random.randint(1, len(s)-3) ; j = random.randint(i+1, len(s)-2)`

Comment: @viraptor: that wouldn't be unbiased, though.  (In the sense of uniform across all possibilities.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [random](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html) module. Specifically, [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.randint).

```
import random

def scramble(word):
    i = random.randint(1, len(word) - 2)
    j = random.randint(1, len(word) - 3)
    if j >= i:
        j += 1

    if j < i:
        i, j = j, i

    return word[:i] + word[j] + word[i + 1:j] + word[i] + word[j + 1:]
```

The range `(1, len - 2)` (both inclusive) will result in an index that is neither the first nor last character.

Comment: Is this the answer to a different question?  The OP seems to want to swap the characters at two different indices, where neither of the indices are 0 or len(word)-1.

Answer (score 0):

(+)operator appends a list or string (in your case) to left hand side list or string. In your code word's characters appends to result from back to front, thus it seems like fliping.

It is generally a good practice to use slicing like `[i:j]`, when working with strings than parsing string characters 1 by 1.

Following code example shows the use of slicing. Most of the time there is a pythonic way to do such operations. Instead of lots of loops and indexing, using slicing, parsers and also regular expressions is simpler and better solution.

```
from random import randint

st = "beginner"

while True:
    i = randint(0,len(st)-1)
    j = randint(0,len(st)-1)
    if i>j:
        i,j = j,i   # swaps i and j
    elif i==j:
        continue
    print i,j
    print st[:i] + st[j] + st[i+1:j] + st[i] + st[j+1:]
```

Here i and j are random integers in range of (0,length of string).

Comment: Looks like an endless loop to me.

Comment: @MikeMüller Only in Python 2.x . In Python 3.x, this code crashes right away.

Comment: yes, loops forever in python 2.x. I write it to demonstrate how slicing works. I beleive showing the way is better for a beginner's question, instead of giving exact function implementation, All you have to do is replacing loop with a function which takes string as arguement.

Answer (score -1):

I would use regular expressions

```
import re
from random import randint

def scramble(word):
    first_group = randint(0,len(word)-2)
    second_group = randint(0,len(word)-2-first_group)
    pattern = "(.{%d})(.)(.{%d})(.)(.*)" % (first_group, second_group)
    print pattern
    scrambled = re.search(pattern, word)
    print "%s%s%s%s%s" % (scrambled.group(1),scrambled.group(4),scrambled.group(3),scrambled.group(2),scrambled.group(5))
```

Comment: **Why** would you use regular expressions? They're hard to understand here, error-prone (this fails in funky ways if newlines are present), slow (lots of unnecessary parsing to do, especially if newlines are present). This seems a prime example of [Zawinski's Law: 
*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.*](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) Additionally, note the inequal distribution - swaps on the very right side are far more likely. On top, this code fails on current (3.x) Python versions.

Comment: @phihag only a word is passed. And it does not seem very slow to me :) flips instantly

Comment: Even then, the distribution is totally skewed. Testing a 100000 times `1234567890` affects these characters: 1: 11024 (5 %),
2: 12350 (6 %),
3: 13825 (6 %),
4: 15414 (7 %),
5: 17453 (8 %),
6: 19314 (9 %),
7: 22016 (11 %),
8: 26013 (13 %),
9: 31362 (15 %),
0: 31229 (15 %).

Comment: One execution is fast, but that's true for almost any implementation of any algorithm. My short testing indicates that [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34193081/35070) is about 2000% faster.